# Unknown margin to the right

Tags: html, css, margin

My div element containing an img element has an unknown large margin towards the right.
I've set the `margin-right` property to 0px explicitly to no avail

```css
#pfpbg {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 5%;
}
```

heres my entire code: https://gist.github.com/ballgoesvroomvroom/1919725a254ffdc34d8fbba8b49d7981
[image]

I believe this is the cause of why it causes the page to overflow horizontally. I'm looking to remove `overflow-x: hidden` in `html, body` styles.

I've tried a simple CSS reset but it didn't solve the issue, margin still persisted.

Comment: Your screenshot shows there is no margin.

Comment: You're required to post a [mcve] in your question, not on another site

Comment: You move an element that has 100% width (default of a `div`) relative 5% from the left. You need to reduce the element width accordingly. `width: calc(100% - 5%);`

Comment: @connexo confused on whats the orange highlighting for since it did say 0 on the margin area

Comment: The orange shows there is is no margin (- is in there). And no margin is shown in the actual image of the window. Can you describe a bit more why you think there is a large margin? And @connexio answer shows why you are getting a scrollbar which is a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

You move an element that has 100% width (default of a `div`) relative 5% from the left. This causes an overflow on the parent element.

### Solution 1

You need to reduce the element width accordingly. `width: calc(100% - 5%);`

### Solution 2

Move the `div` using a `margin-left` instead (depending on other margins in ancestor elements, this might not work):

```css
#pfpbg {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```